# How to add div under selected text in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div containing a few lines of text. On text selection, I want to insert a div containing an input tag right below the selected text. I am able to insert the input tag approximately below the text but there's this whitespace the size of input field that gets prepended to the selected text every time I select a text to add the field.

Question: How do I fix this (remove whitespace that gets prepended to the selected text)?

```js
function createInput() {

  var _tripleClickTimer = 0;
  var _mouseDown = false;

  document.onmousedown = function() {
    _mouseDown = true;
    ClearSelection();  
  };

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    _mouseDown = false;

  };

  document.ondblclick = function DoubleClick(evt) {
    ClearSelection();
    window.clearTimeout(_tripleClickTimer);

    //handle triple click selecting whole paragraph
    document.onclick = function() {
      ClearSelection();
    };

    _tripleClickTimer = window.setTimeout(RemoveDocumentClick, 1000);
  };

  function RemoveDocumentClick() {
    if (!_mouseDown) {
      document.onclick = null;
      return true;
    }

    _tripleClickTimer = window.setTimeout(RemoveDocumentClick, 1000);
    return false;
  }

  function ClearSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection)
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection)
      document.selection.empty();
  }

  if (window.getSelection().toString()) {

    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var inputObject = document.createElement("input");
    inputObject.className = "objId";
    div.className = "annotations";
    
    div.appendChild(inputObject)
    div.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(div);


  } else {
    // window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    //console.log("empty selection")
  }

}
```

```css
#description {
  line-height: 4em;
  height: 113px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  line-height: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 43px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.objId {
  width: 85px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, 4em);
}

.annotations {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;
}

.descriptionBox {
  padding:10px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #4f534f;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #bab9b9;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: -90px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius:8px;
  -webkit-border-radius:8px;
  border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="createInput();" id="description" class="descriptionBox">Nunc tincidunt leo eget libero imperdiet placerat. Nunc sollicitudin ac urna a viverra. Cras fringilla, ipsum molestie facilisis lobortis, turpis odio pulvinar diam, ut rutrum dui felis vel justo. Mauris felis nisl, pretium ullamcorper nisl at, fermentum
  placerat purus. Donec a velit sit amet felis tempus placerat in a arcu.</div>
```

Comment: have you tried with negative margin after selection?

Comment: Could you show with an example how would I do that?

Comment: Negative margin doesn't decrease the size of the yellow whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.objId` class – this way, it won't take up space within the other, relatively positioned elements.

As you have set a line-height in ems, I would keep the same units when positioning the element vertically – a `margin-top: 4em;` without `transform` places the input right below the highlight's beginning.

Comment: Thank you that worked!. Any suggestions on how to get the input field below the text? I changed the transform to **transform: translate(-11%, 243%);** but for the left most selections the input fields is not showing at the bottom of the text selection.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the left most text selection in line 2 and 3, the input fields don't get inserted right below the selected text. It goes to the top right above the line 2. Tried it with margin-top but didn't work.

Comment: `translate(0, 4em)` looks good to me, except for the right edge, where it changes the width of your container. 
Alternatively, `.annotations` can get a `position:relative;`, and position the `.objId` with `top: 2em;`. 
However, as you are already using JavaScript, you can use that one for positioning. :)

Comment: I made the edits you suggested in the code above. So when I select any word or phrase at the start of the line, the input field doesn't show below the selection but goes up above the line on the right side. Example: try selecting the word: pulvinar on 3rd line.

Comment: Please look at the latest edit as I added the css for the parent div I am actually using for my project. On selecting the left-most word in line 2, the field moves up.

Comment: The only way the input gets inserted below the selected text is if I change the display to **inline-block** for **.annotations**, but the height of selected text is quite large. I tried decreasing the height of **.annotations**, it does decrease it but then I'm not able to align the decreased background with text selection as they are both part of same div.

Comment: You can add a `span` within your annotations and only set the background-color for that inline element – while the inline-block container gives you more flexibility when positioning the input.  
(In other news, I still couldn't reproduce the "field going up" issue, but the leftmost words' input field still gets into the next line. )